# How can I find out if there's a traffic light in the route given an array of lat, long (GPS positions)?

Tags: openstreetmap, gps, traffic

I've the minutely (60 seconds) GPS trail of a vehicle travelling in USA. I want to find out if in the particular 60 second GPS trail there's a traffic LIGHTS/SIGNS or not.

Can I get this information from OSM database?

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! We encourage one question per question. Feel free to split the second question "how" into another question. https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

OSM data is crowd sourced so it all depends on where you vehicle has traveled and how active the OSM community is in that area.  Simple answer I guess would be yes OSM data does allow for signs and traffic lights systems to be mapped however, it'll be down to you to check whether the data is accurate enough for what you need.

This info can be downloaded from [geofabrik.de](http://geofabrik.de), clicking downloads on the right and then going through the selection process to get to where you want to download.

If the data is not good enough or the route isn't too long you could always trawl Google street view and check signs/ light that you come across.

Comment: Alternate download process through Mapzen: https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts/